# Left-justify geom_text layer with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

`ggplot2` automatically centers the text in a `geom_text` layer. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(text = c("A short sentence.",
                      "A slightly longer sentence.",
                      "This sentence is the longest of the sentences."),
             y = row_number(text) - 1,
             x = 1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = text), nudge_x = nchar(text)/2)
```

Produces:

ggplot:

[image: link to ggplot (I'm not allowed to post images yet)]

However, I want to left-justify the text in a neat column. I'm essentially asking how to provide an `xmin` to the `text`. Do I need to perform a mathematical operation on the `x` variable that scales `x` accordingly? Or is there a trick with `theme`?

Comment: see also https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-do-i-set-an-xmin-argument-to-geom-text/785/3

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `hjust`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = text), hjust = 0)
```

You can also add an `xlim` to align the column to the very left side of the plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = text), hjust = 0)  + xlim(1, 1.5)
```

[image]